# Trigger a javascript function after select multiple option from <select> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi select  tag is here. I like to call a function after select multiple option from select tag.

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If any body mark as duplicate please let me know the correct link. I search lots here and google also. but non of solution is good for my problem.

Comment: Hook to the `change` event and count the length of the `:selected` elements.

Comment: Thanks for down vote. i tried a lots of solution. i can not mention here all. so i didn't mention any of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to `change` event in the same way as you do this with non-multiple `select`:

```js
$("#cars").on('change', function() 
{
  var selectedItems = $(this).find("option:selected");

  if (selectedItems.length <= 1)
  {
      $("#result").text("not multiple!");
      return;
  }
  
  var text = "";
  $.each(selectedItems, function() {
      text += $(this).val() + " ";
  });
  
  $("#result").text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: your answer is good but on click each option this function is called. i like to call the function after select multiple option

Comment: @Janny Oh, haven't understood this. Just check if `selectedItems.length > 1`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I like to say, If user want to select 3 item then after 3 selection function will call. if user want select 4 option then after 4 option select function call.

Comment: @Janny you can call that by using if else, all you need is the length of option selected

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali look like you not able to understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with help of `change()` and `blur()` event handler

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  if ($('option:selected', this).length > 1) {
  // set custom data attribute value as 1 when change event occurred and selected options are greater than 1
    $(this).data('select', 1);
  } else
    //set value as zero in other case 
    $(this).data('select', 0);
}).blur(function() {
  if ($(this).data('select')) {
    // when focus out check custom attribute value
    alert('selected more than one');
    // code here
    // call your function here
  }
  $(this).data('select', 0)
  // set custom attribute value to 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: your answer is good but on click each option this function is called. i like to call the function after select multiple option.

Comment: then use blur event, it will fire when focusout

Comment: If we don't change anything blur also work. i am looking only after change only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.change` instead like so :

```
$('select').change(function(e){
  var length = $('option:selected', this).length;
  if ( length > 1 ) {
    alert('hey');  
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/mtvwv1vg/)

Comment: Please read the comments from other answer and then answer. I am waiting for modify answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will call a function passing the newly selected value into `functionToCall`.

```
var values = [];
$('select').change(function(e){

    var current = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    });

    var newValue = $(current).not(values).get();
    values = current;

    if(newValue.length)
        functionToCall(newValue);
});

function functionToCall(value){
    alert(value);   
    console.log(value);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtvwv1vg/2/)